# How could I support HDCP2.2 in Android miracast?

Tags: android, miracast, hdcp

I want to support miracast with hdcp2.2 and using mediaplayer, how could I support hdcp2.2? Should I apply hdcp2.2 to MediaDrm plugin?

I see widevine hdcp test video in exoplayer test cases, but now I don't want to support widevie. Is it same thing as hdcp in miracast?